# How do I select employees most profitable case's?

Tags: sql, database

In ms sql I've run across a query I need to do but can't wrap my head around it.

I've simplified it to an employee case that I can apply to my situation.

```
Employee: [EmpID, Name]
Case    : [CaseID, EmployeeID, CaseName, Profit]
```

How do I select an employees most profitable case against his name?

I'd like a result like,

```
Result  : [EmpID, Name, CaseID, CaseName, Profit]
```

Comment: what dbms? there are optimal ways to do this if we know the database system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM   Employee e
       INNER JOIN Case c ON c.EmployeeID = e.EmpID
       INNER JOIN (
         SELECT EmployeeID, MAX(Profit) AS Profit
         FROM   Case
         GROUP BY 
                EmployeeID
       ) pmax ON pmax.EmployeeID = c.EmployeeID
                 AND pmax.Profit = c.Profit
```

*Note that this is not complete if you have cases for employees with identical profits. For those cases, you would add another join to the mix*

Comment: @Lieven - Think, instead of MAX it should be SUM. Places where same emp has worked on multiples cases.

Comment: @Sachin, I don't think so (but could be wrong). *for the record, I didn't downvoted you*

Comment: There are employees with identical profits in my case, I don't see why yours isn't complete though. You've grouped by EmployeeID surely? (oh wait I get it - same employee same profit.. ahh that's not a problem :)) ty

Comment: Employees with identical profits is not a problem. An employee with multiple cases with the same profit is. What case do you want to have returned in that case (no pun intended).

Comment: @Lieven - Hey, its not about downvote, anyway my answer was wrong. Not bothered about that. Dont worry. Just thought, there can be multiple records in CASE with same empID, but OP should tell that.. :)

Comment: Ty this works for me :) but too quick to accept as an answer :D

Answer (score 0):

How it works in mysql

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html